# Finding highest date with criteria

Tags: excel, date

I'd like a formula to find the highest date based on 2 columns: Column `A` is shipping date; Column `B` is delivery date; Column `C` is where I want the results to be.

The logic is: What is the last day I can place an order this month and still receive the shipment before the last day of this month. The results is based on the entire columns. The results could be on another cell, not necessarily on results column.

Here's the an example table:

| Shipping Date | Delivery Date | Results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/24/2023 | 01/28/2023 | 01/26/2023 |
| 01/25/2023 | 01/30/2023 | 01/26/2023 |
| 01/26/2023 | 01/31/2023 | 01/26/2023 |
| 01/27/2023 | 02/01/2023 | 01/26/2023 |

Hope someone could help me!

Comment: if WHAT is true?

Comment: The lowest is the min which would be 1/24, no?

Comment: What would be the expected output in case the logical condition is `FALSE`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write highest!

Comment: To be honest idk if it is a case of true or false, but if it is false, just return 0.

Comment: I think what you mean logically then is:  "What is the last day I can place an order this month and still receive the shipment before the last day of this month."  What version of Excel? If you are an O365 customer this gets amazingly easy, BTW.  Also...  It is actually easier to return the last date somewhere else, in a predetermined cell on the worksheet, rather than repeating it in every row in column C.

Comment: @Synth would you update your question based on the comments? It is not clear if you result is comparing the data on each row or based on the entire data set. Would you explain the logic in your question for some of the sample results provided.

Comment: @MaxR I'm using 365, you got the logic right.

Comment: @DavidLeal Done, I think I write it better now.

Comment: Thanks @Synth it took more time to understand the problem than to solve it, :-). That is why it is so important to spend sometime writing a well defined question. I hope it helps. Please let me know if that is what you are looking for. Thanks **@MaxR** for clarifying the real intention of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `E2`, use the following formula:

```
=LET(delivery, B2:B5, shipping, A2:A5,
  BYROW(shipping, LAMBDA(a, MAX(FILTER(shipping, MONTH(delivery) = MONTH(a)))))
)
```

Here is the corresponding output:
[image: sample excel file]

Basically by row we filter the `shipping` dates to consider only the `delivery` is during the same month, and from there we take the maximum date.

**Note**: You can't use `MAXIFS(max_range, criteria_range1, criteria1)` to replace `MAX(FILTER())`, because the second input argument *must be a range*, and we have an array after applying the `MONTH` function.

Comment: Thank you for the aswer, but I don't know why my excel, although being 365 doesn't allow me to use BYROW formula. Is there another formula that is possible to use?

Comment: @Synth that is weird. Just to make sure would you check this simple call works: `=BYROW({10;20},LAMBDA(p_one,SUM(p_one)))`. According to Microsoft link: [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) is available for O365 with no constraint. Are you sure you have O365? Check [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm) which functions work in your version. It can be done with `MAP`, but I don't know if it is available in your version.

Comment: @Synth you can use the non SPILL version, put the following formula in `E2` and then extend it down: =`MAX(FILTER($A$2:$A$5, MONTH($B$2:$B$5)=MONTH($A2)))`. It is the same logic, just that it returns the result just for one cell. Let me know.

Comment: is returning value, I'm trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, the last formula is working! Thank you so much.